# Rust: Problem creating Struct by a factory method

Tags: rust

take this minimal repro ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6fb21bafd96a05fb66cfdc29fe0f38f8)), where i try to have a struct with a closure as a field, and define some additional factory methods that provide custom logic in form of a closure.

```
#![allow(non_snake_case)]

struct FunStruct<T>
where
    T: Fn(i32) -> i32
{
    pub p: T,
}

fn Create<T>() -> FunStruct<T>
where
    T: Fn(i32) -> i32
{
    let p : T = |val| -> i32 {
        return val;
    };
    
    let a = FunStruct {
        p,
    };
    
    return a;
}

fn main() {
    let a = Create();
    
    println!("{}", (a.p)(5));
}
```

the above snippet throws the following error.

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:14:17
   |
10 |   fn Create<T>() -> FunStruct<T>
   |             - this type parameter
...
14 |       let p : T = |val| -> i32 {
   |  _____________-___^
   | |             |
   | |             expected due to this
15 | |         return val;
16 | |     };
   | |_____^ expected type parameter `T`, found closure
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                     found closure `[closure@src/main.rs:14:17: 16:6]`

error[E0282]: type annotations needed for `FunStruct<T>`
  --> src/main.rs:26:13
   |
26 |     let a = Create();
   |         -   ^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `T` declared on the function `Create`
   |         |
   |         consider giving `a` the explicit type `FunStruct<T>`, where the type parameter `T` is specified
   |
   = note: type must be known at this point

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0282, E0308.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0282`.
```

however, this seems to work just fine

```
struct FunStruct<T>
where
    T: Fn(i32) -> i32
{
    pub p: T,
}

fn main() {
    let p = |val| -> i32 {
        return val;
    };
    
    let a = FunStruct {
        p
    };
    
    println!("{}", (a.p)(5));
}
```

one level of abstraction seems to ruin it.

Comment: You can have a look at https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-05-advanced-functions-and-closures.html#returning-closures. Looks like "Rust doesn’t know how much space it will need to store the closure" (which is a bit strange, because the compiler seems to have a lot of info about the closure), so one has to store it on the heap.

Comment: @ForceBru i'm not returning a closoure, though and i'm givin all the info the compiler needs regarding sizes. in fact, i'm giving it more info in the example that doesn't compile than in the example that does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic parameter means that it works for any type - however, the closure in `Create` does *not* work for any closure type, it creates a closure with one, specific type. You can do this:

```rust
fn Create() -> FunStruct<impl Fn(i32) -> i32>{
    let p/*: some anonymous, unique type */ = |val| -> i32 {
        return val;
    };
    
    let a = FunStruct {
        p,
    };
    
    return a;
}
```

An `impl Trait` in return position means "I return some type that implements this trait, I'm not going to tell you what it actually is though". In contrast your original function says "Given any type that is a function, I can return it" - which obviously doesn't make sense.